# MySQL dump .sql script and import to an apache derby

Tags: mysql, export, derby, ansi

So presumably [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) can export to [ansi compatible](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible) format so that you can import to other vendors' databases.

However trying to import to an apache derby I face all this syntax errors.
Thought I try some regex and fix things but it seems that there are more than a couple.

Is there something I'm missing about mysqldump?
Tried [ddlutils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/) but couldn't make progress after step 3 with these [docs](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/db_ddlutils.html) which seem out of date.

Do I have any other options with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqldump` option `--compatible=ansi` doesn't produce a SQL script that is *fully* ANSI compatible, it just tries to produce a result that is *more* ANSI compatible: "Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or with older MySQL servers."

Unfortunately, the SQL syntax supported by each database is a bit different. SQL is a relatively weak standard, much weaker than Javascript or even C. Some databases support compatibility features like MySQL does, or even [compatibility modes](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) (disclaimer: I'm the main author of H2), but even this is not enough sometimes.

You have multiple options: you could change the generated SQL script by hand, or you could use another tool to copy the table structure / data. One such tool is the [SQuirreL DB Copy Plugin](http://dbcopyplugin.sourceforge.net/) (I have never actually used it, but from what I heard it works well).

Comment: although it doesn't seem to solve the problem without any quirks it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you can export your data in CSV format, or something similar, then you can use the Derby data import procedures to import your data: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefimportproc.html